# Android - No view found for fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to get my replaced fragment to appear in the detail fragment but after debugging my app on a tablet emulator and selecting the necessary list view item, the log cat gives me this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0050 (com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite:id/detail_container) for fragment FragmentWCBank{3b4ea8fb #0 id=0x7f0c0050}

I really don't understand why I'm getting this error when my fragment is there within my project. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

**FragmentWCLine.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentWCLine extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Station_key";

    private class WC {
        private CharSequence station;
        private CharSequence zone;
        private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;
        private Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass;

        public WC(int stationResId, int zoneResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass, Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass) {
            this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
            this.station = getResources().getString(stationResId);
            this.zone = getResources().getString(zoneResId);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return station.toString(); }
        public String getzone(){ return zone.toString(); }
    }

    private static WC[] mWC;

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wc_line, container, false);

        // Instantiate the list of stations.
        mWC = new WC[]{
                new WC(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, WCBankActivity.class, FragmentWCBank.class),
                new WC(R.string.wat, R.string.zone_1, WCWATActivity.class, FragmentWCWAT.class)
        };

        final ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_wc);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mWC));
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(mTwoPane){

                    setItemNormal();
                    View rowView = view;
                    setItemSelected(rowView);
                }
                else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].activityClass);
                    String station = mWC[position].station.toString();
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, station);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            public void setItemSelected(View view){
                View rowView = view;
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66CCCC"));

                TextView tv0 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                tv0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));

                TextView tv1 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
            }

            public void setItemNormal()
            {
                for (int i=0; i< listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View v = listView.getChildAt(i);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                    TextView tv0 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station));
                    tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    TextView tv1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone));
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B5B5B5"));
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView station;
            TextView zone;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        WC[] mWC;

        public MyAdapter(Context contexts, WC[] samples) {
            this.mWC = samples;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mWC.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mWC[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        /**set selected position**/
        private int selectPosition = -1;
        public void setSelectPosition(int position){
            if(position!=selectPosition){
                selectPosition = position;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.station = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                viewHolder.zone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.station.setText(mWC[position].station);
            viewHolder.zone.setText(mWC[position].getzone());

            //change item color
            if(position==selectPosition){
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
                viewHolder.station.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
            }else {

            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

**WCBankActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;


public class WCBankActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Station_key";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_wc_bank);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Get the message from the intent
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            // Notice to specify the sender Activity for the message
            String station = intent.getStringExtra(WCBankActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            FragmentWCBank newFragment = new FragmentWCBank();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentWCBank.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentWCBank extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wc_bank, container, false);

        return v;
    }
}
```

**fragment inflation**
[image]
[image]

**fragment_wc_bank.xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/detail_container">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Bank"
        android:id="@+id/textView0"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_wc_line.xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentwcline">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_wc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/master_container"
    android:name="com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite.FragmentMainList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**activity_main.xml layout (sw600dp)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/master_container"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/detail_container"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Undesired result**
[image]

Comment: Please show which code causes the Exception error. I suspect is the code in WCBankActivity class but I m not sure. Simply click on the error or debug code one line at a time to figure out which code causes the error. I know I have been repeating this advice.

Comment: It is the code in **WCBankActivity**. Btw it is the mTwoPane stuff which is now and has been the problem since yesterday. It won't replace the detail fragment!

Comment: You need to show your layouts, meaning at least 2 xml files, especially for fragment_wc_bank. This will save time. This issue has nothing to do with fragment code logic. This is strictly layout and GUI ID issue.

Comment: Just added codes for 4 layouts where I think at least 1 of them is the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code transaction.replace(R.id.`detail_container`...Now this may be the correct UI element. I am assuming this is the correct UI. If so, `fragment_wc_bank` layout xml does not have that ID `detail_container`, hence you get error, simple as that. However **activity_main.xml** has that ID, again I am assuming `detail_container` is the correct UI that you want.

Suggested code FROM:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_wc_bank);
```

TO:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main.xml);
```

Notes:

1. **activity_main.xml** is the only difference between the 2 codes above.
2. This is a common error but we all have to learn from this. Learn more about layouts. It is a critical knowledge in making Android apps.
3. There are **2 different activity_main.xml** files you posted. They should at least be similar. Otherwise you could be very confused.

Comment: I hope this time you can appreciate my posted answers plus comments. I think I have spent enough time. I need to help others as well. Good luck...

Comment: It opens up in a completely new view but I don't want that. All I want is the fragment_wc_bank fragment to appear in the detail fragment, that's all. Check the screenshot under **Undesired result**

Answer (score 2):

Your activity is trying to inflate a layout, then place a fragment into it in place of the view detail_container.  detail_container does not exist in that layout-  either you forgot to add it or you're inflating the wrong thing.  I notice you're inflating R.layout.fragment_wc_bank for both the fragment and the main activity, my guess is you're inflating the wrong layout in the activity.

Comment: Just to clarify I want to inflate R.layout.fragment_wc_bank in the detail_container is mTwoPane is true (tablet screens). However if mTwoPane is false (non-tablet screens) then I want WCBankActivity to open, which would contain the R.layout.fragment_wc_bank fragment. Based on this, what code would suggest to change?

Comment: I'd create a new layout for WCBankActivity that has a ViewStub in it with the id detail_container.  Then your activity should inflate that and inflate the fragment into it.  Then you shouldn't need any additional code changes, just the xml file and change to the id you call setContentView on.